# SharePoint 2013 Online - Default Wildcard Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365

Is there a way I can change SP to always append a * to the end of every search?

We're using the Online version (tied in with O365), and it has been requested that we have every search be a wildcard search by default. I found walkthroughs for SharePoint 2010, but the interface and menus have changed in 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the Search Results Web Part. Then from the web part properties, click on `Change Query`.

Now in the popup modal window, click on "Advanced Mode".

In Query text, you can use `{SearchBoxQuery}*`

Comment: When I click Web Part Properties from the Search Results page, I don't see "Change Query" anywhere in the Web Part window - Is there another way to get there?

Comment: Can you see Search Criteria?