# Cannot search by partial document title in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

I cannot search documents by partial title on my search result page **/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?**

I have some documents with title **PLANS_COMPANY_OF_OFFICE_MOD_EAE01**, if I search by keyword **EAE01**, it works.

If I search by keyword **EAE0**, it does not work. No search result displays.

Comment: Have your searched Stack Overflow for Wild Card search?

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123015/sharepoint-2013-online-default-wildcard-search

Comment: @DannyEngelman Hi, my search result page is **/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?** I cannot modify this page.